# How do I query with lower and associations in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an association, I want to query by a value of the association's field. E.g. "Get all of the associations where the Role.name is 'admin'". I also want to lowercase the value of Role.name.

The relationships for the item is `has_many :roles`, while the other side is `belongs_to`. Here is what I have:

- Works, but not lower case: `.where("roles.name":"Admin")`
- Errors, even without lower case: `.where("roles.name = ?","Admin")` generated SQL is `WHERE (roles.name = 'admin')`
- Fails, without error or lower case: `.where('"roles.name" = ?',"Admin")` generated SQL is `WHERE ("roles.name" = 'admin')`

What I really want is to be able to say `.where('lower("roles.name") = ?',"Admin")`, but how do I do that?

The error is usually one of `SQLException: no such column: roles.name`.

As requested, `schema.rb`:

```
  create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "roles", ["name"], name: "index_roles_on_name", unique: true
```

Comment: Please, provide schema.rb part, where roles table is.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work only with Role model, just try:

```
where('lower(name) = ?', 'admin')
```

If you want to do it from another model (Eg. User), try this in User model:

```
User.joins(:roles).where('lower(roles.name) = ?', 'admin')
```

Comment: Yes, I am doing it from another model, but the `where('lower(roles.name) = ?','admin')` returns an SQL error